# Websocket connection not working on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying a node js application with a WebSocket connection.

```
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8888");
```

This is working fine with desktop browsers.
But does not work with mobile browsers.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: When using mobile browsers its calling websocket.onclose = function(evt) {} , so I am not able to work with it.

Comment: Well, for starters, `127.0.0.1:8888` would be trying to connect to port 8888 on the mobile device itself.  Is that really what you're trying to do?  Is your websocket server on the mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I needed it use the public ip of my PC instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Can anyone suggest how this can be practical since my IP address can change based on the system I am running this?.